# Scan and recreate QR code

Tags: applications, qr-code

Does anyone know of a way (preferably a single app) that could scan and recreate a QR code?

Eg. I point my phone at the code, and then I could display that code on the screen, so it can be scanned again by some other device. This is different from simply taking a picture of the QR code since it takes me longer to get a nice photo of the code and even if I do, the quality is still quite bad and it takes too long to scan the code with the other device.